# Docusign embedded sending. Missing the "Send" button

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using sandbox account on my 'dev' website. Today I saw that the "send" button in sender's view disappeared. You can see it in the screenshot. Why is it happened, does anybody know? [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1pCh.png)

Comment: so in embedded iframe this button disappeared. Please, if you're downvoting my question - please tell what i'm doing wrong. I can provide a code, that i use on this page to receive the link for embedding, but the same code works fine with 'production' credentials. I cannot find any info about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a issue with our embedded sending experience in iFrames on our Demo environment yesterday, where the header bar wasn't rendering.

A fix was pushed out late in the day. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue yesterday as well. I have been in touch with DocuSign and they believe this was due to an issue with the New DocuSign Experience having some connectivity blips. 
https://trust.docusign.com/en-us/system-status/ You can see the EU environment had some connectivity issues yesterday. 
I hope this answers your question as to why this was happening yesterday

Comment: @CodingDawg, it wasn't my question so I don't think I can edit their question with this information. Apologies if this didn't count as an answer, I thought I had covered everything that would help the person who asked this.